# Конвертер hex to dec

Tags: shell

Как можно конвертировать шестнадцатеричные числа в десятичные в `shell` ?

Вот так неправильно почему-то :

```
echo "obase=16 ;3C9D" |bc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bb=0xa
aa=`printf "%d" $bb`
echo $aa
```

Печатается:

```
10
```

Comment: a=3C9D ; aa=`printf "%d" $a`; echo $aa

bash: printf: 3C9D: invalid number
3

Comment: 1. надо шестнадцатеричные числа писать с префиксом 0x

2. printf и последующий тескт вставить в обратные кавычки ` или $()

У меня все работает

Comment: можно смешнее `echo $((0xa))`

Comment: @alexlz, тоже можно, но если надо присвоить значение переменной, все равно нужно кавычки ставить. Кроме того, читал в одной умной книжке пространные рассуждения о преимуществах printf перед echo

Comment: про кавычки понятно все гуд !

Comment: @mikillskegg `a=$((0xb)); echo $a`

Comment: @alexlz, снимаю шляпу. Оформи в виде ответа, я плюсик поставлю

Comment: @mikillskegg Надеюсь шляпу снимаете не с меня? (У меня её всё равно нет)
`h2d() (printf %d 0x$1)` вызов `h2d aa`

Comment: если нужно часто вызывать, можно и функцией.

а значение переменной можно тогда так присваивать

a=$(h2d b)

Comment: @alexlz, я с других шляпы не снимаю. Только золото и бриллианты

Comment: да неплохо! плюсую